# Why would experimental Mach #s in a wind tunnel be higher that Mach #s predicted by theory (inviscid) for the same nozzle geometry

Tags: wind-tunnels

The figure below shows the mach numbers across a supersonice convergent-divergent nozzle.

Since the experimental Mach numbers (calculated from measured pressures along the walls of the nozzle) take into account viscous forces, shouldnt their mach numbers be lower than that of the theoretical inviscid predictions? Similar to the trend of the CFD (viscous) calculations?

[image]

Comment: Was something missed / ignored or assumed in the theory? What error is possible for the physical measurements? There is a tolerance to every measurement.

Comment: Was heat flow modelled also? The temp changes quite a bit with a 2 Mach expansion. The gas model also needs to be very good. What tap location is the throat at and what real gas model were the predictions made with?